# Selecting earliest date using linq/lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following expression

```
 var list = techlinks.GetItems().Where(p =>  p.Status == 1).ToList();
```

I want to change this so that I want to select the earliest date value for example

```
 var list = techlinks.GetItems().Where(p =>p.Date is earliest && p.Status == 1).ToList();
```

Please let me know what to insert for p.Date is earliest

Thanks

Comment: Hint: `DateTime` implements `IComparable`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you can use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending()` to sort them on Date this way:

```
var list = techlinks.GetItems()
                    .Where(p => p.Status == 1)
                    .OrderBy(x=>x.Date).First(); // this will give oldest date
```

and:

```
var list = techlinks.GetItems()
                    .Where(p => p.Status == 1)
                    .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).First(); // this will give latest date
```

Comment: This solution returns a single value matching the oldest/latest date, not the list, as the expression used in the question suggests.

Comment: OP wants to get earliest date record

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way.

```
var list=techlinks.GetItems()
                  .Where(p=> p.Status==1)
                    .Min(d => d.Date)
                      .Single();
```

Answer (score 3):

If there might be multiple items all with the earliest date:

```
var list = techlinks.GetItems()
    .Where(p => p.Status == 1)
    .OrderBy(x=>x.Date)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
    .First()
    .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Student student = _context.Set<Student>()
          .Where(p => p.StudentID == ID.Value)
          .OrderBy(p => p.AddedDate)
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

It slightly depends on what `GetItems()` of `techLinks` does, but something like that should work:

```
var list = techlinks.GetItems().Where(p => p.Date == techlinks.GetItems().Min(x => x.Date) && p.Status == 1).ToList();
```

If `GetItems()` method actually hits the database, you can store its result first and use it twice:

```
var allItems = techLinks.GetItems();
var list = allItems.Where(p => p.Date == allItems.Min(x => x.Date) && p.Status == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Why multiple queries?

Comment: No need to GetItems twice.

Comment: This wouldn't even compile since `techlinks.GetItmes().Min(x=>x.Date)` would return a `DateTime` which cannot be ANDed with a `bool`.

Comment: @tdragon I've taken back my downvote, but having a "subquery" will make this inefficient.  At the very least I'd compute the min value outside the `Where` call.

Comment: @juharr - as I wrote - it depends on whether `GetItems()` method executes database call or not. But you might be right - I do not know what would be faster - find min date first and then select items with that date or order whole table to get first/last item.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but this answer is still inefficient. DB call or not, it'll still loop the collection twice.

Comment: If think looping a collection to find single value (min date) and then filter by this value, comparing to ordering the whole collection to get 1 top result are 2 very different operations. Moreover, the solution with `FirstOrDefault()` returns just one result, and the question suggests (by using `ToList()`) that the author is looking for a collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want 1 you could go with

```
techlinks.GetItems().Where(p => p.Status == 1).OrderBy(c => c.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

otherwise I'd break it up into two statements

```
var date = techlinks.Min(c=>c.Date);
techlinks.GetItems().Where(p => p.Status == 1 && c.Date == date).ToList();
```

also be aware of how your dates are inserted, DateTime.Now will add time components so might have to do something gnarly like this

```
techlinks.GetItems().Where(p => p.Status == 1 && c.Date.Year == date.Year && c.Date.Month == date.Month && c.Date.Day == date.Day).ToList();
```

Comment: For that last one you can just use `DateTime.Date` to compare only the date portion without the time.

Comment: @juharr - if it's a Linq to Entities - you can't

Comment: @tdragon True, but this doesn't look like Linq to Entities.